# Difference between membership and inclusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inclusion-exclusion

I've taken the definition of membership to be the following:

Membership $A \in B: A$ is one of the members of $B$.

However, I'm not sure where to make the distinction between membership and inclusion, and hence I can't wrap my head around the solutions to the following questions:

"Say whether the following are true or false"

h. $\{2\}\in\{x:x$ is a number between $1$ and $9\}$  (False)

i. $\{2\}\subseteq\{x:x$ is a number between $1$ and $9\}$   (True)

and similarly,

n. $\emptyset\subseteq\{a,b,c\}$ (True)

o. $\emptyset\in\{a,b,c\}$ (False)

I am not sure why (h) and (o) are false but (i) and (n) are true, i.e. I don't see how the same element can be a subset but not a member of the same set.

Is it possibly because membership is only valid between an element and a set rather than a set and a set, while inclusion is valid between a set and a set?

I would appreciate any help in clarifying this, thank you.

Comment: The problem you are having is that you are not seeing the distinction between sets and the elements within a set. {2} is not the number 2.  It is a set that has the number 2.  h) sets the set with the number 2 is an element of a set of numbers.  That is patently impossible.  If {x: x is a number between 1 and 9} is a set of numbers then only numbers can be members.  And {2} is not a number it is a set.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response. However I'm still not entirely sure why ∅∈{a,b,c} is false though while ∅⊆{a,b,c} is true? As I don't know whether the empty set should be seen as a set or an element (or lack thereof)

Comment: "I'm still not entirely sure why ∅∈{a,b,c} ".  Well, what are the elements of {a,b,c}?  They are a,b,c.  Are any of a,b,c the same thing as the empty set?  No, none of them are.  So the emptyset is not an element of {a,b,c}.  *NOTHING* should be seen as an element unless it actually *is* an element.  Notice $\emptyset \in \{fred, george, \emptyset\}$ because the emptyset *is* in the set.  And $\emptyset \not \in \{fred, george\}$ because the empty set is *not* in that set.  It really is that simple.

Comment: I understand now why the empty set cannot be a member of {a,b,c}. hHowever, is that fact that the empty set can be included in the set {a,b,c} because every set includes the subset ∅? I.e., ∅⊆{a,b,c} (True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{2\}$ and $2$ are entirely different things.

$\{2\}$ is a set that has $2$ as its only element-- it is a set and it is not a number.  And $2$ is a number-- it isn't a set.

What are the members of $\{x: x$ is number between $1$ and $9\}$?  Well those members are: $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$.  Are any of them the same thing as $\{2\}$?  Nope.  Not a single one of those numbers between $1$ and $9$ is the set with $2$ as its only element.  So $\{2\}\not \in \{x: x$ is number between $1$ and $9\}$.

Are any of those members the same thing as $2$; the number $2$?  Yes, $2$ is the same thing as $2$.  So $2 \in  \{x: x$ is number between $1$ and $9\}$

Is $\{2\}$ a subset of $\{x: x$ is number between $1$ and $9\}$?  Well, is $\{2\}$ a set?  Yes.  What are its members?  Its member is $2$.  What are the members of $\{x: x$ is number between $1$ and $9\}$?  They are $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$.  Are all of $2$ in the list $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$?  Yes, it is.

So $\{2\}\subset \{x: x$ is number between $1$ and $9\}$.

Is $2$ a subset of  $\{x: x$ is number between $1$ and $9\}$?  Well, is $2$ a set? No, it is not.  What are its members?  It's not a set; it doesn't have any members.

So $2 \not \subset \{x: x$ is number between $1$ and $9\}$.

.....

"how the same element can be a subset"

An element can not be a subset at all.

$\{2\}$ is not an element of $\{x: x$ is number between $1$ and $9\}$

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these examples

$$2\in \{1,3,2\} $$

$$\{2\}\in \{\{1\},\{3,4\},\{2\}\} $$

$$\emptyset\in \{\{3,5\},\emptyset\} $$

a set belongs to a set of sets.

a set is included in a set which contains its elements.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however I'm not sure how this helps me to distinguish the difference between being a member and being included?

Comment: The problem you hare having is *not* about being a member and being included (which are exactly the same thing) but about the difference between being an item, and being a set that contains the item.  {2} is not 2.  and 2 is not {2}.  {2} is not a number.  {2} is a set.  2 is not a set.  2 is a number.  {2} is not a member of a set of numbers because {2} is not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Inclusion: If all objects inside set A are also inside set B, $A \subset B$.

Membership: If set/object A is itself inside set B, $A \in B$.

For example, let $A= \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$.

$A \subset \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\},$

while $A \in \{\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}, 1, 2, 3\}$ (this could also be written $A \in \{A, 1, 2, 3\}).$

(Now... what can we say about $A$ and the set $\{\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}?)$

Comment: Thank you for your reply! If I take my example then- {2}∈{x:x is a number between 1 and 9} (False)- would I be right in saying 2∈{x:x is a number between 1 and 9} is true (because 2, without the brackets around it, is now an element rather than a set?)

Comment: It is false that $\{2\}$ is in the set because the set $\{2\}$ not the same as the number $2$.  $\{x: \text{x is a number between 1 and 9}\}$ is a set of *numbers* $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$.   However, you are right that $2 \in  \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$. (Now, if the set in question looked like $\{1, \{2\}, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$, then we would have $\{2\}$ as a subset.)

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response. However I'm still not entirely sure why ∅∈{a,b,c} is false though while ∅⊆{a,b,c} is true? As I don't know whether the empty set should be seen as a set or an element (or lack thereof)

Comment: The statement "Every element of $\{\}$ is an element of X" is vacuously true for all sets $X$, since there are no elements in $\{\}$. So the empty set is a subset of every set. (It is not an element of every set: $\{\} \in \{\{\}, 1, 2\},$ but the empty set is not an element of $\{1, 2, 3\}$)